# T-SQL : check a table column only has negative value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | -2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | -1 |

I only want to have a results of distinct col1 which having only col2 are ALL negative.

Which means I want to have only see col1 = 2

How to do that?

Comment: `group by col1 having max(col2) < 0`?

Comment: doh you beat me to it, feel free to post an answer @GSerg and ill remove mine

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT col1 from table1 t
group by t.col1
having max(t.col2) < 0
```

you can select just col1 from your table where the max value of col2 is less than 0 after grouping by col1.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08ed9b/25/0